# Append new test results to an existing newman report

Tags: postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

I am using the following code snippet to run all collections in a folder using POSTMAN's npm module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/**
 * @fileOverview Read all collection files within a directory and run them
 * in parallel.
 */
var newman = require('../'), // require('newman')
    fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir('./examples', function (err, files) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    //Filter all files with JSON file extension
    files = files.filter(function (file) {
        return (/^((?!(package(-lock)?))|.+)\.json/).test(file);
    });

    //Iterate on each file name and call newman.run using each file name
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        newman.run({
            collection: require(`${__dirname}/${file}`)
        }, function (err) {
            // finally, when the collection executes, print the status
            console.info(`${file}: ${err ? err.name : 'ok'}!`);
        });
    }); 
});
```

If I try using

```
{
    collection: require(`${__dirname}/${file}`),
    reporters: 'html',
    reporter: { html: { export: './result/htmlResults.html', template: './templates/htmlTemplate.hbs' } }
}
```

instead of

```
{
    collection: require(`${__dirname}/${file}`)
}
```

Every new collection run by `newman.run` will overwrite the report file `htmlResults.html`. I am looking for a way to append test data from new collections to the existing report. Is there a way to achieve this?

Note: I do not wish to create multiple report files(individual reports for each collection)